# How to correctly update pandas dataframe from a filtered dataframe that has datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm currently working on a dataframe named `df` that requires first to filter it to a new dataframe named `df1` based on `date` and `num_posts column`, next step is set the value of `num_posts column to 10` and increment `date column by one month` of the filtered `df1`.

the logic to filter `df` to `df1` is:

if `date == today & num_posts == 4`.

The last step once i update the selected columns for `df1` mentioned above, is to update `df` from `df1` with this line of code `df.update(df1)`

What is working.
I'm able to filter `df` to `df1` based on the logic and update `date and num_posts` columns within the filtered `df1`.

What is not working
When i try to update `df` from `df1`, it only updates the `date column`, but cannot update `num_posts` values.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_posts': [5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 14],
                   'date': ['2022-06-10', '2022-06-14', 
                            '2022-06-14', '2020-09-12', 
                            '2020-09-29', '2020-10-15'],
                  'user': ['user4', 'user1', 'user1', 'user3', 'user4', 'user4']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Logic one start
# Get current date
new_date = datetime.datetime.now()
current_date = new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# filter posts that equal 4 and date equal today
df1 = df.loc[(df['num_posts'] == 4) & (df['date'] == current_date)].copy()


# # overwrite the num_posts column with 10
df1.loc[df1['num_posts'] == 4, 'num_posts'] = 10
# df1.replace({'num_posts': {4: 10}}, inplace=True)

# Increment date by one month
plus_month_period = 1
df1 = df1['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=plus_month_period)
df1
# updating the old dataframe
df.update(df1)
df
```

When i run my code i get the following output which is not the intended output.

```
    num_posts   date    user
0   5   2022-06-10  user4
1   4   2022-07-14  user1
2   4   2022-07-14  user1
3   4   2020-09-12  user3
4   1   2020-09-29  user4
5   14  2020-10-15  user4
```

What i Expect as output once i run my code above(have modified it manually).

```
    num_posts   date    user
0   5   2022-06-10  user4
1   10  2022-07-14  user1
2   10  2022-07-14  user1
3   4   2020-09-12  user3
4   1   2020-09-29  user4
5   14  2020-10-15  user4
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign column `date`:

```
df1['date'] = df1['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=plus_month_period)
```

Or:

```
df1['date'] += pd.DateOffset(months=plus_month_period)
```

---

```
df.update(df1)
print (df)
   num_posts       date   user
0        5.0 2022-06-10  user4
1       10.0 2022-07-14  user1
2       10.0 2022-07-14  user1
3        4.0 2020-09-12  user3
4        1.0 2020-09-29  user4
5       14.0 2020-10-15  user4
```

Alternative solution is assign to original DataFrame by mask and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
new_date = datetime.datetime.now()
current_date = new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
plus_month_period = 1

m = (df['num_posts'] == 4) & (df['date'] == current_date)
df.loc[m, 'num_posts'] = 10
df.loc[m, 'date'] += pd.DateOffset(months=plus_month_period)
print (df)
   num_posts       date   user
0          5 2022-06-10  user4
1         10 2022-07-14  user1
2         10 2022-07-14  user1
3          4 2020-09-12  user3
4          1 2020-09-29  user4
5         14 2020-10-15  user4
```